# laravel unit test index function in controller

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

this is my index function

```
public function index($alias, $profileId)
{
    $this->setClientAndClientProfile($alias, $profileId);

    $routeData = Routedata
                        ::where('client_id', $this->client->id)
                        ->paginate(10);

    return view('client.route_data.index', compact('routedata'))->with('client', $this->client)->with('clientProfile', $this->clientProfile);
}
```

setClientAndClientProfile is function just to check type of user and bring his profile

so how to write a test for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can simply assert that the view returned by the route has routedata.

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->call('GET', '/path/to/my/controlller/method');

    $this->assertViewHas('routedata');
    $this->assertViewHas('client');
    $this->assertViewHas('clientProfile');
}
```

However, you could take this one step further and you could make assertions about the type of data that was sent to the view.

First, grab the data:

```
$routedata = $response->original->getData()['routedata'];
$client = $response->original->getData()['client'];
$clientProfile = $response->original->getData()['clientProfile '];
```

Now you can test the `instances` of these variables to ensure they were properly set as well:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection', $routedata);
$this->assertInstanceOf('\App\Client', $client);
$this->assertInstanceOf('\App\ClientProfile', $clientProfile);
```

All together it would be something like:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->call('GET', '/path/to/my/controlller/method');

    $this->assertViewHas('routedata');
    $this->assertViewHas('client');
    $this->assertViewHas('clientProfile');

    $routedata = $response->original->getData()['routedata'];
    $client = $response->original->getData()['client'];
    $clientProfile = $response->original->getData()['clientProfile '];

    $this->assertInstanceOf('\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection', $routedata);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('\App\Client', $client);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('\App\ClientProfile', $clientProfile);

}
```

I made assumptions about the types of `$client` and `$clientProfile`, so you should adjust the classes accordingly.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: without make login test ?

Comment: and what do you mean in this '/path/to/my/controller/method'
u mean the controller file that contain  index method?

Comment: @flower The `route`. So if it was the `ClientProfile` controller, maybe `/client-profiles`

Comment: i checked from route list i see this


|        | GET|HEAD                       | backend/route-data                                                       | backend.route-data.index                                    | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\RoutedataController@index                       | App\Http\Middleware\Backend |

Comment: @flower Then you would use `/backend-route-data` as your route.

Comment: :) i try as u write up but i got this 1) RouteIndexTest::testIndex The response was not a view. Failed asserting that false is true

Comment: @flower Sorry, my route was wrong, it should be `/backend/route-data`. Anyway, if it didn't return a view then you know something is wrong.

Comment: how i can check the id and get data which is belong to this id ??

Comment: @flower the `data` is part of the 3 variables that I assigned off of the response, you can see that `$routedata`, `$client`, `$clientProfile` are all defined. This is out of the scope of this question, at this point. Please accept this and make a new question.